Mueller matrix for mirrors and lenses?
I am new to Mueller calculus, which was a topic we never discussed in University and which I have now started to work with. I am trying to find out the final polarization state of light. I have the following optical setup:
S-M-M-LP-LP-PEM-L-D
where S states Source (a QCL laser), M states for Mirror, LP for linear polarizer, PEM for photoelastic module, L for lens and D for detector, respectively.
I have been consulting the literature (Wikipedia, Eugene Hecht´s "Optics" and O´Neill´s "Statistical Optics"), and while I can define the Mueller matrix for the LP´s, which I believe is the following:

I haven´t found out out how to define it for a mirror or a lens. If I understand properly, the PEM can be described as a quarter-wave retarder. I believe I can extract the information regarding the phase difference of the fast- and slow-axis from the manual.
Unfortunately, I have no one who can help me on the topic, thus asking here for your help into understand what and if I am doing something wrong. Should you know some good reference book on Mueller calculus that could help me better understand it, I would be very thankful!

Googling Mueller matrix of mirror turned up a few hits that might be useful. Here is one A polarization model for the German Vacuum Tower Telescope from in situ and laboratory measurements

Are you assuming front-surface metal mirrors?

@CarlWitthoft, indeed. Plano-mirrors.
